# Discord.py on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to have my bot give someone a certain role whenever someone reacts to a certain message

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.id == 747566918466273300 and reaction.emoji in "✅":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Member")
        await bot.add_roles(user, role)
```

and i get error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bruker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because the [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction%20add#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event does not take a `user` or a `reaction` parameter, you have to use `payload` instead, for example:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # Code here
```

Then for the rest of your code:

```
if payload.message.id == 747566918466273300 and payload.emoji.name == "✅":
    role = discord.utils.get(payload.guild.roles, name="Member")
        await payload.author.add_roles(role)
```